# Installing developer libraries for Fedora 19 without internet connection

Tags: fedora, software-installation, drivers, rpm, wlan

I am trying to use Fedora 19 on my Lenovo Yoga 13. A common issue with this setup is that the laptop's Wi-Fi does not work out of the box on any Linux distribution yet. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74110/i-can-not-get-my-realtek-8723-driver-source-compiled) and also [this question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/9633/i-can-not-get-my-realtek-8723-chip-to-work/) is very similar to mine, in which the askers found working WLAN drivers but had trouble installing them. However, in my scenario to `make & make install` the driver, I apparently need the following packages:

```
kernel-headers kernel-devel gcc patch
```

Because I don't have working wireless or an Ethernet port, I effectively can not use `yum` to install these from the Internet. I have attempted downloading the rpm packages myself on another machine, transferring them via a flash drive, and using `rpm -Uhv` to install each one, but they appear to need endless dependencies that I do not have from installing Fedora 19 via a live USB. I gave up after a few hours of trying to navigate these lists of dependencies.

Is there a better way of installing required development packages in order to install a driver when I have no Internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `yum install` from a local repository rather than a network one. If you haven't installed any updates on your system (and it sounds like you haven't), you can use the [installation DVD](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options#formats) (although not the Live CD / Live USB) version. There are instructions for this [in the install guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/sn-switching-to-gui-login.html#sn-enabling-repos); the quick version is to mount the DVD somewhere (like `/mnt`) and create an `/etc/yum.repos.d/dvd.repo` file like this:

```
[dvd]
baseurl=file:///mnt/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch
```

and then just go ahead and `yum install` from this repository. By default, yum will attempt (and fail) to access your networked repos, so you have to either edit the config files to disable them, or run your yum command like this:

```
 yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=dvd install ...
```

If you don't have a DVD drive, you can do something similar with a USB stick onto which you've copied the contents of the Fedora 19 repository. Of course, you don't really need the whole thing, but just getting it all is the easy way to avoid having to figure out the dependency chain yourself.

Comment: Thanks, thanks the fact that there is a local repo on the dvd image was the missing information I needed. However, after setting all this up I run into a problem with using `yum install`. See my edit for further information. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try `yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=dvd ...` to tell it to not use any other repositories. (Or edit the .repo files to disable them.)

Comment: Thanks that did it! I don't really understand why `yum` is not configured to try another repo after failing to connect an online one, but I've managed to install the wlan driver on Fedora now!

Comment: If you set up the _same_ repo with multiple sources, it will fall back. If you have multiple repositories configured but one doesn't work, it takes the conservative choice of bailing out.

Comment: @kikumbob To make this more helpful to someone in the future, I'm going to edit the answer to reflect the above, roll back your question to the previous version, and delete all this chit-chat. :)